# Script Component unable to work without breakpoint

Tags: ssis

I have scenario of pulling data (i.e. different column values) from XML source file using script component. I have an issue for one of the column which it is not fetching the actual value from the source file. It always displays the value as null.

But whenever i debug the code using breakpoints then the column is fetching actual value from source file. Basically it works when i enable the breakpoints. can any one help?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post that will help you craft a question that is likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you post the piece of code where you think the value needs to be fetched and is not? Also, having the sample xml file would help.